# Bazaar offline + branches

Tags: bazaar

I have a Bazaar repository on Host A with multiple branches. This is my main repository.

Until now, I have been doing checkouts on my other machines and committing directly to the main repository. However, now I am consolidating all my work to my laptop and multiple VMs. I need to be working offline regularly. In particular, I need to create/delete/merge branches all while offline.

I was thinking of continuing to have the master on Host A with a clone of the repository on the laptop with each vms doing checkouts of the clone.

Then, when I go offline, I could do bzr unbind on the clone and bzr bind when I am back online.

This failed as soon as I tried to bzr clone since bzr clone only clones a branch(!!!!)

I need some serious help. If Hg would handle this better please let me know (I need Windows support.) However, at this moment I cannot switch from Bazaar as it is too close to some important deadlines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want something strange. None of existing DVCS will handles this as you want. You'd better to create local copy of your main repository and just sync it with host A regularly. Bind/Unbind dance has some undesired side effects.

Comment: I think you are right. I am doing this now and it works. I'm not sure what I want is strange at all. I develop some software on my own and part of that means doing concurrent development (bug fixes + new features.) It is reasonable to continue that offline. I don't understand how I would use bzr to do this without doing some silly rsync. I could just as well do this with Subversion.

Comment: Are you aware of push and pull commands?

Comment: Yes, but they don't seem to work well with bzr branch which is the method I am using.

Answer (score 0):

bzr fundamentally works with one branch / directory (the branch are visible at the file system level), so if you need to clone each branch from your repository (not unlike svn, in a way). Hg, at basic level, works this way too (although you can put several branches in one repository using say named branches).

For DVCS, it is important to distinguish between the following:

- Working tree: a versioned set of files (at a given revision)
- Branch: a linear set of revisions
- Repository: a set of revisions

When you clone locally a directory versioned by bzr, you are copying the repository subset which contains all the revisions in the branch you are cloning, and get the working tree. This assumes you are not asking for a branch wo a working tree nor using a shared repository.

What you want, IIUC, is to clone the full repository with all the branches. There is no 'native' way to do so in bzr I believe, but plugins to help you toward this, like multi-pull and push-repo, to sync multiple branches in one shot.

But I don't understand why that's such a big problem, or the link with working offline: you just clone the branches you want to work on your laptop.

Comment: I see. So the fundamental issue is that I should have created a trunk/branches structure like in SVN? That makes so much sense if so.

Comment: Hmm, no that's not what you are saying.

Comment: God, no, the whole point of DVCS is to go away from the broken SVN model for branches and tags :)

But when you clone with bzr (and hg), you are copying a subset of all the revisions, the ones attached to the branch you are cloning. Generally, you do NOT want to get every branch (I think that this is linked to a fear of losing some revisions and influence of CVS/SVN).

Comment: Actually, even with git where the model is all the branches in a single repository, when you clone a repository, you get only one branch, at least by default. Getting every branch of a repository is very unnatural for development IMHO.

Comment: David, your comment heads into wrong direction. Checkouts in bzr works almost like checkouts in svn/cvs. And topic starter wants to have checkouts behavior.

Comment: David, the point is that I want/need to do branched development offline and sync up when I get back online. How can I do that with a DVCS? It seems that is not allowed?

Comment: nothing is disallowed, but some things are easier than others. multi-push/multi-pull does not do what you want ?